# unicode character with apache ignite with multiple nodes

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, ignite

I'm trying to cache my unicode data using apache ignite. When I use one node, I don't have any problems but when I use multiple nodes, my unicode data corrupted.

For example, consider I have two values `ĂĆ, Ɇɜɷ` for my data, when I use one node my sqlquery groupby returns these two values, but when add new node my groupby result have these 4 records: `ĂĆ, Ɇɜɷ, ??, ???`

How can I solve this problem?

**update 1:**

In this [code](https://gitlab.com/babak/ignite-unicode/tree/master), I have three classes: Main class, Person class and PersonManager.

I run the project three times and each time, I add 100 persons to the person cache and use sqlquery for groupby in each node and broadcast it. When I run the 3rd node, in first and second one I see three records of data while before it I saw two records.

Comment: Do you have a unit test that reproduces this issue? Can you share it?

Comment: I don't have unit test but I share sample code.

Comment: Can you paste the output? I ran the test and didn't observe any issues.